# How do I recover a deleted file too large to go to recycle bin?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

I mistakenly deleted a very important 50 gb file from my 1 tb hard drive, and the file was too big to go to recycle bin. How do I recover it?

Comment: This may be a question best suited for a different SE site (maybe superuser?). Are you using Windows Backup or another backup tool? Have you checked the built-in Windows File History tool? As a last resort, you can find file recovery software by googling. Don't use the disk at all if possible until you've recovered the file, to avoid overwriting it.

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking for is called "**Carving**". This is a program that reads the raw disk (not the directories) looking for start/stop identifiers and attempts to output everything in between the matching filetype start and stop as a file. This is how files are recovered or undeleted, they are still present they're just no longer allocated in the directory after a delete.

Carving needs to be run from another system against the disk being carved. There are numerous carvers available, the classic is "Scapel" but I'm fond of "**Photorec**". Contrary to its name, Photorec recognizes and recovers hundreds of different filetypes, not just photos. In particular it can be directed to carve only unallocated (*deleted*) space so you don't end up recovering files that aren't lost.

In your case, a 50GB unallocated space has a pretty high likelihood of being partially over written, and thus unrecoverable, pretty quickly if you continued to use the system. Nevertheless it's worth a try. I would suggest using a bootable Linux system that has file recovery software ready to go. ***Kali*** is a good option and you can find numerous Youtube videos to explain file carving.

In the event that file carving fails, there is one other *possibility*. Windows recovery functions ***may*** have a *shadow volume* of your deleted file. If present, it will be a back version missing the most recent changes but it's easy enough to look for it.

Back versions can be looked for under *right-click* *File/Properties/Previous Versions*, but if the file has been deleted you obviously cannot right-click it. Instead you need a *Shadow Volume Reader*. There are many, but you may want to look at [ShadowExplorer](https://www.shadowexplorer.com/downloads.html).

Good Luck, and let us know your results.

Comment: Very good answer.